# Auto Layout and Image Views/Views

Tags: xcode, view, autolayout, imageview, constraints

Hi I'm trying to understand auto layout and have a simple question.  Correct me if I am wrong, but unlike labels and buttons, image views/views do not have an intrinsic content size which makes working with them in auto layout a tad bit harder.  I just want to know what constraints I would need in the examples below so they would show up appropriately in both portrait and landscape, if I were to be working in the W:Any H:Any size class.

In the case of the image view I was also wondering if the outcome would change if I were to apply the constraints and then the image.

https://s15.postimg.org/s5814ct3f/Screen_Shot_2016_09_03_at_6_20_22_PM.png

https://s9.postimg.org/jxdeud13j/Screen_Shot_2016_09_03_at_6_20_56_PM.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this:

1) Select an imageView, and choose following 4 constraints:

- top leading contraint
- width constraint
- aspect ratio constraint (so it is going to be dependent on its width and it won't be distorted)

[image]

- horizontal center in container constraint

[image]

If you are likely to need to change the image size after you've implemented the autolayout, you may need to **change constraints**. Thye are responsible for handling items and their sizes, rather than then dimensions (width, height) that are in size inspector.

I made a little animation to see, how to change constraint in interface builder, while you are designing your scene:

[image]